# SVG cursor has unwanted grey edge

Tags: html, css, svg

i'm trying to use svg for a cursor and getting crappy grey edges.  only happening with not vertical or horizontal edges (it was happening with diagonals as well as this circle) on certain color backgrounds.

tried messing with shape-rendering and borders but that didn't seem to help.

seems like maybe there's a shadow being automatically rendered or something?  i don't know much about svg so maybe this is something obvious or just the way of the world.

edit:  seeing this in chrome & safari

cursor css:

```
cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill:#EAFB4C;"/></svg>'), pointer;
```

```css
body {
background:rgb(215, 248, 3);
cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill:#EAFB4C;"/></svg>'), pointer;
}
square-cursor {
display:block;
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid blue;
cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100" ><polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100" style="fill:#EAFB4C;"/></svg>'), pointer;
}
dark-background {
display:block;
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:blue;
cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill:#EAFB4C;"/></svg>'), pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
<square-cursor></square-cursor>
<dark-background></dark-background>
same svg dot not as cursor below:<br><svg width="100" height="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill:#EAFB4C;"/></svg>
</body>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Not seeing any grey edges?

Comment: I see them in Chrome. Probably a rendering issue. With webkit. I think it's better to use a PNG instead. Or if you really need to render the SVG, you might want to actually render an inline SVG element and hide the cursor.